Factorization of $x^5 +1$ on $\mathbb{F}_7$
My Algebra's book affirms that $x^5 +1$ factors into $x^5 +1 = (x+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$ on $\mathbb{F}_7$. Is this correct? Shouldn't it factor into $x^5+1 =(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$?

Even easier, you can just multiply it out. So over $\Bbb F_p$, for every prime $p$, we have
$$
(x+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=x^5 + 2x^4 + 2x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 1.
$$
This is different from $x^5+1$ for $p=7$, but correct for $p=2$. So my guess is that $\Bbb F_2$ was misread (or mistyped) as $\Bbb F_7$.

You are right, the correct factorization is $x^5+1 =(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$.
Most books have some mistakes in them - if it doesn't look right, there is a chance it is wrong!

You are entirely correct, and such a factorization can easily be checked through wolframalpha.com:

factor(x^5+1)mod7

returns:

(x + 1) (x^4 + 6 x^3 + x^2 + 6 x + 1) (mod 7)


Is there a way to get wolframalpha to factor extension fields, such as factor(x^32+x^22+x^2+x+1 modulo(x^16+x^12+x^3+x+1)) mod2 ?

If you let $x=1$, the books's factorization gives
$$2\equiv 2\times5\pmod7$$
which is false. Your factorization gives
$$2\equiv2\times 1\pmod7$$
which is true. Your guess is better.
